# Can I use an identity to go from $\sin(2\pi(\omega(t + h) + \beta))\sin(2\pi(\omega t + \beta))$ to $\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\pi \omega h)$?

Tags: trigonometry, time-series, trigonometric-series

In my time series homework I had to compute the periodogram of a periodic series and in the solutions we have a step that goes from $\sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \sin(2\pi(\omega(t + h) + \beta))\sin(2\pi(\omega t + \beta))$ to $ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \cos(2\pi \omega h)$?

After endless algebra I think I got there via using several identities.
Though my prof usually writes them all out, so I am guessing that since he didn't here, I am missing some obvious identity that lets me go there in one step?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: $t$ and $h$ are integers?

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo Yes they are

Comment: Also, in the second sum, the one with $\cos$, the index is $t$, but there is no $t$ in the expression

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo I think this is correct, it comes out as just the sum of $n-h$ times the cosine term. At least this is what I got too after a long (very possibly wrong) journey.

Comment: something to know about $\omega$ and $\beta$?

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo no, these are unknown.

Comment: Well, if you put random real numbers for $\omega,\beta$ and integers positive numbers for $h,n$, you get different results, so they are not the same

Comment: Would you have an example of when they are not the same @VincenzoTibullo ?

Comment: Data: $h=3, n=10, \omega=1.2, \beta=1.4$, we get $\sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \sin(2\pi(\omega(t + h) + \beta))\sin(2\pi(\omega t + \beta)) = -0.904508$ while $ \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \cos(2\pi \omega h) = -2.42705$

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo thank you very much for this example, I noticed there is a 1/2 missing out front but even then your example shows something different. I'll try again to verify and will also check with my professor. Thanks again!